# Can you make your save unplayable by saving at a bad moment?

Tags: fnaf-security-breach

Been watching some youtubers play Five Nights at Freddys: Security Breach, so I can't really test this myself.

The game lets you save at some save points, but those points are not in safe/neutral rooms. So you could basically save a second before a game over.

So if you play it in an Ironman way (always saving over your savefile) and do the mistake of saving in a way where its impossible to not dodge the game over coming your way, did you make your save file impossible and unrecoverable?

Answer (score 2):

Probably yes, this happened to me once. I had just beat the first section with the Endos and was trying to save, but then I did, turned around and an Endo was right behind me. I tried loading again but I couldn't turn in time and died even faster. Luckily I had made a backup save just before the Endo section, but if you don't have a backup save then I think you may have to start back from midnight.

Comment: @TheBird956 What are you on about?  It provides an answer based on anecdotal evidence.  Like most answers on this site.